# STM32 using CubeMX and STMStudio: 'int main()' doesn't work

Tags: c, debugging, stm32, adc

I'm learning to code on STM32F429ZI Nucleo board and I've been trying to read temperature from ADC1 temperature sensor using STMStudio.

The code I found in one of tutorials didn't work so I tried checking value of "check" variable at various parts of code and then I've noticed that, not only the value of "check" variable doesn't change anywhere inside the main function, but also the STMStudio doesn't see any variables declared inside of the main function.

Any idea why is that?

I've tried different code which uses button to light up LED to check if the board is ok and it worked just fine.

```
    /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint16_t SenseADC;
float check = 0;
float Temperature;
float Vsense;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

  check = 2;
  const float V25 = 0.76; // [V]
  const float Vsupply = 3.0; // [V]
  const float ADCResolution = 4095;
  const float avg_slope = 0.0025; // [V/deg. C]
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

      if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,10) == HAL_OK){
          check = 3;
          SenseADC = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
          Vsense=(SenseADC*Vsupply)/ADCResolution;
          Temperature = (Vsense - V25)/avg_slope + 25;

          HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

      }
  }
```

}

Comment: It looks like at least two curly braces are missing at the end, can you please check you code snippet for completeness? Thank you

Comment: The brackets are okay, I must have missed them while copying the code. It's edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler must have noticed that the `check` variable is only written and never read, and optimized away the writes as having no purpose. For debugging purposes, you can declare it as `volatile` to force all writes to get through to memory.

The `const` values in the program are likewise victims of the optimization, the compiler has used the values directly in the code, possibility precalculating parts of the expressions.

Comment: after making it `volatile` the `check` variable still shows up as 0.0. The `SenseADC` variable shows constant value of 15474. The ADC resolution is set to 12 bits so it shouldn't have value greater than 4096 and it certainly should not be constant.

Comment: Then something is fundamentally wrong with your compiler or debugger setup.

Comment: Okay, I managed to find the solution, for some reason it didn't upload new version of the program to the microcontroller if previous one had the same file name. After uploading it with external software and then checking value with STMstudio it showed up good results.